# ZIP: Include parent directory (PHP)

Tags: php, zip

I need some help, I have code for zipping a folder, my problem is it does not include the target or parent folder in a zip file.

```
  Test
    -- 1
    -- 2
```

only 1 and 2 is in the zip file, I want to include the Test directory.

This is my code

```
$source='/testing';
$destination='/test';

$img_dir = array("1", "2");
$arrlength = count($img_dir);


   foreach ($img_dir as $k => $v) {
    zipData($destination.'/'.$v, $destination.'/img_'.$v.'.zip');
}

function zipData($source, $destination) {
    if (extension_loaded('zip')) {
        if (file_exists($source)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
                $source = realpath($source);
                if (is_dir($source)) {
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        $file = realpath($file);
                        if (is_dir($file)) {
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                        } else if (is_file($file)) {
                            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (is_file($source)) {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, as far as I can see you simple don't add the parent directory to the archive. You have condition `if (is_dir($source)) {` and inside it you iterate through files inside and add just them. So I don't understand very well what's the problem.

Comment: You're already adding subdirectories inside the parent directory (`$zip->addEmptyDir()`) to the archive, so just add parent directory there the same way.

Comment: If you want to add a directory and all subdirectories look at `::addGlob()` [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addglob.php) It may save you doing a lot of this processing

Comment: @DawidFerenczy sorry im new to this, I cant get it .

Comment: Just read you code line by line: after `$zip->open()`, you check if your path in `$source` is directory (`if (is_dir($source))`). Then you iterate through files and subdirectories in that directory (`foreach ($files as $file) {`) and add them to the archive. So you just need to add root directory to archive before you start adding files and subdirectories inside it (after opening it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to add whole directory tree to an archive is to use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

You have a nice example in PHP manual, which is actually exactly what you're trying to write yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php. You should always check the manual first.

It's in the first user comment:

```
Zip a folder (include itself). 
Usage: 
  HZip::zipDir('/path/to/sourceDir', '/path/to/out.zip'); 

<?php 
class HZip 
{ 
  /** 
   * Add files and sub-directories in a folder to zip file. 
   * @param string $folder 
   * @param ZipArchive $zipFile 
   * @param int $exclusiveLength Number of text to be exclusived from the file path. 
   */ 
  private static function folderToZip($folder, &$zipFile, $exclusiveLength) { 
    $handle = opendir($folder); 
    while (false !== $f = readdir($handle)) { 
      if ($f != '.' && $f != '..') { 
        $filePath = "$folder/$f"; 
        // Remove prefix from file path before add to zip. 
        $localPath = substr($filePath, $exclusiveLength); 
        if (is_file($filePath)) { 
          $zipFile->addFile($filePath, $localPath); 
        } elseif (is_dir($filePath)) { 
          // Add sub-directory. 
          $zipFile->addEmptyDir($localPath); 
          self::folderToZip($filePath, $zipFile, $exclusiveLength); 
        } 
      } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
  } 

  /** 
   * Zip a folder (include itself). 
   * Usage: 
   *   HZip::zipDir('/path/to/sourceDir', '/path/to/out.zip'); 
   * 
   * @param string $sourcePath Path of directory to be zip. 
   * @param string $outZipPath Path of output zip file. 
   */ 
  public static function zipDir($sourcePath, $outZipPath) 
  { 
    $pathInfo = pathInfo($sourcePath); 
    $parentPath = $pathInfo['dirname']; 
    $dirName = $pathInfo['basename']; 

    $z = new ZipArchive(); 
    $z->open($outZipPath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE); 
    $z->addEmptyDir($dirName); 
    self::folderToZip($sourcePath, $z, strlen("$parentPath/")); 
    $z->close(); 
  } 
} 
?>
```